# saving a xlsheet to pdf = document not saved

Tags: excel, pdf

I am trying to save a sheet as pdf file apparently, it's just giving me an error message saying Document not saved. As I debug all are good but when I debug I go over Type it says TypePDF=0

Please kindly help. thank you
Please make note that the target sheet is active.

Thank you

```
Dim path As String
Dim fn1 As String
Dim fn2 As Date
Dim fn3 As String

path = "C:\Users\Christine Cordero\Desktop\Evercrete Philippines Transactions\Clients\Transaction Invoices"
fn1 = Range("CustomerNameLine").Value
fn2 = Range("InvoiceNumberDate").Value
fn3 = Range("InvoiceNumberLine").Value

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'this is one code I was trying to save only a range of that sheet.   

' Save Invoice as PDF Option 1
Range("Print_Area").SaveAs filename:=path & fn1 & " " & fn2 & " " & fn3 & " " & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenDocumentSpreadsheet
```

End Sub

'The code above does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I know this is just a simple question and finally, I was able to figure it out.

The problem was when I manually save the file as pdf there is a prompt for marker setting option and so I guess that's what stopping the code to function and so I instead set the IncludeDocProperties=False and it worked.